# How to extract data from between subgroup heads in Python using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, tags, beautifulsoup

I am extracting data from tables using BeautifulSoup.  This table has players listed under Transfers In/Transfers Out subgroup heads, all of which are grouped under a "group-head" specifying the football team they are going to.  I want to iterate through each team and subsequently each sub-head (Transfers in/out) so that I may specify the group-head (team) as either the incoming or outgoing team based on if the player was listed in Transfers in or out.  Here is the html:

```
<tr class="group-head">
    <th colspan="4"><h3><a href="/teams/england/arsenal-fc/">Arsenal</a></h3></th>
</tr>

    <tr class="subgroup-head">
        <th colspan="4">Transfers in (&euro;25.5M)</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="odd">
        <td class="date"><span class='timestamp' data-value='1341093600' data-    format='mm/dd/yy'>07/01/12</span></td>
    <td class="player"><span class="flag_16 left_16 france_16_left"></span>O. Giroud</td>
    <td class="team">Montpellier</td>

    <td class="type">&euro; 12M</td>
  </tr>
```

I would iterate through the subgroup-head classes to get data, but the tr tag ends with each subgroup so I cannot look at the data below the tag.  The output I'm trying to get is a dictionary with this format:

{Player:  [To team, From team, Price, Date]}

How do I grab the html??

UPDATE:

I started a loop to iterate through siblings, as each one was spaced out by two consecutive ones, although it still has problems.  Is there an easier way?  I want to make sure it doesn't catch teams or other subgroups:

```
teams = table.findAll('tr', {'group-head'})
inout = table.findAll('tr', {'subgroup-head'})

for team in teams:
  for direction in inout:
    details = direction.next_sibling.next_sibling
    print details.text.encode('utf-8')
    while details.next_sibling.next_sibling:
      if details.next_sibling.next_sibling not in inout:
        if details.next_sibling.next_sibling not in teams:
          print 'NEXT ONE'
          details = details.next_sibling.next_sibling
          print details.text.encode('utf-8')
        else:
          break
```

It doesn't seem to want to past first team, and adding additional breaks doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can locate the `<tr>` tags with class `subgroup-head`, and then use the [`next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) operator to get the next row. Then drill down into the  elements and get the information you need.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
subgrouphead = soup.find('tr', 'subgroup-head')
details = subgrouphead.next_sibling.next_sibling
```

And get the information you need from here.

Comment: That would work if there was only one player per subgroup, however there are multiple players for each section, so it wouldn't be able to iterate over all of them.  I'm trying to see if I can call next_sibling.next_sibling until it reaches another subgrouphead...

Comment: @user1549620 it looks like each player is in a row, so you just need to iterate through next_sibling looking for <tr> tags. Should be straightforward in a loop.